# How do I place mines?

Tags: pc, far-cry-4

I already had a similar problem with fire arrows and got the helping answer here.  I can't seem to find out how I am able to use/place mines on the PC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you cared to look at the customize controls options you'd see this:

[image]

The answer is 0, Zero. Have fun.